# How to delay the gui update?

Tags: python, time, pysimplegui

I am going to make the prototype have two question

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import random
import time

def corecode(base):
    return ("\n"+"-"*0+"\n").join([f'{i+1:>2d} X {base:>2d} = {(i+1)*base:>3d}' for i in range(10)]) 
def test():
    question = ["What is 9 X 9 ?", " 1. 81", " 2. 12", " 3. 22", " 4. 68"]
    return '\n'.join(question)
def test2():
    question2 = ["What is 3 X 8 ?", " 1. 45", " 2. 64", " 3. 24", " 4. 35"]
    return '\n'.join(question2)
def Praise():
    Praiseword = ["Good Job!!!","Hope you have a great day!","Good Bye!!"]
    return '\n'.join(Praiseword)
def Wrong():
    Wrong = ["You do wrong, try again :)"]
    return '\n'.join(Wrong)
sg.theme('LightBLue')
sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 12))
showrobot_column = [
    [sg.Image('E:/img/Gif_robot.gif', size = (700, 700))],
    [sg.Exit(),sg.Button('Return to study',key='-Return-',visible=False)]
]
showtest_column =[[sg.Button(str(i+1), size=(15, 1), expand_y=True)] for i in range(4) 
]
list_values = [f'{i+1:>2d}' for i in range(10)]
show_Textbox_selectbox = [
    [sg.Txt('Multiplier table',key='-txt-',visible = True)],
    [sg.Multiline(size=(20, 20), expand_y=True, key='-MULTILINE-')],
    [sg.pin(sg.Listbox(values=list_values, enable_events=True, size=(15, 10), key="-LISTBOX-")),
     sg.pin(sg.Button('Test Yourselves', key="-Test-"))],
]
layout = [
    [sg.Column(showrobot_column, expand_y=True),
     sg.VSeparator(),
     sg.pin(sg.Column(showtest_column, visible=False, expand_y=True,key='-Buttons-'), expand_y=True),
     sg.Column(show_Textbox_selectbox, expand_y=True),],
]
window = sg.Window("First Test", layout, finalize=True)
multiline = window['-MULTILINE-']
multiline.update(value=corecode(1))
listbox = window['-LISTBOX-']
listbox.update(set_to_index=0)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event =='Exit':
        break
    elif event == '-LISTBOX-':
        base = int(values[event][0])
        multiline.update(value=corecode(base))
    elif event == '-Test-':
        multiline.update(value=test())
        window['-Return-'].Update(visible = True)
        window['-txt-'].Update(visible = False)
        window['-LISTBOX-'].Update(visible = False)
        window['-Buttons-'].Update(visible = True)
        window['-Buttons-'].expand(expand_y=True)
        window['-Test-'].Update(visible = False)
    elif event in (str(i+1) for i in range(4)):
            if event == '1':
                multiline.update(value=Praise())
                time.sleep(2)
            else:
                multiline.update(value=Wrong())

                multiline.update(value = test2())
    elif event == '-Return-':
        window['-Buttons-'].Update(visible = False)
        window['-LISTBOX-'].Update(visible = True)
        window['-Return-'].Update(visible = False)
        window['-txt-'].Update(visible = True)
        multiline.update(value=corecode(1))
        listbox.update(set_to_index=0)
        window['-Test-'].Update(visible = True)
window.close()
```

, but the question between question should show the Praise() or if it do wrong show Wrong(), but if I set time.sleep(2) it will stop the whole program and do not run the multiline.update(value=Praise()), how can I make a delay and it will update the multiline first ?

Comment: `update` method just to update the configuration of GUI, not the GUI itself. To get update GUI immediately, call `window.refresh()`.

Comment: It's better to use `sg.popup_auto_close` to show your message, and set how long it wait in option `auto_close_duration`.